# Signal function to be activated only in child in C

Tags: c, process, signals

My goal : I would like to reproduce Ctrl C (SIGINT) and Ctrl \ (SIGQUIT) in a shell-like programm I am myself coding for a school project.

For this purpose, I am using signal function.
I am for now able to trigger a custom function whenever I reach Ctrl C or Ctrl , that prints something.

The problem I am now facing is that I would like this custom function to be triggered only when in a child process of my shell.

I am using fork to create processes when receiving commands. For example, when using cat, Ctrl \ should exit this command with "Core Dump", but should do nothing when triggered in my prompt. I have no idea how to "distinguish" parent from child.

I already tried puting this signal(SIGQUIT, handler) when doing my fork (when pid == 0, just when executing the command), but it doesn't work and I am pretty confused where this function should be used. Here is what I tried unsuccessfully.

In my sigquit handler, where I print getpid() and getppid(), there are always the same and are the PID of my program, and my "real" terminal's one.

First thing I tried is simply to put it in my main, but it handles both parent and child process, even if it kills (even if I don't even call kill, I simply assume that commands handle signal themselves ?) only the command (and do not exit my shell, which is what I am looking for).

```
{
    printf ("SIGNAL QUIT\n");
    printf ("%d %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
}

int main(int ac, char **av, char **envp)
{

    signal(SIGQUIT, quithandler);
    while (1)
    {
        line = readline("prompt> ");
        if (line && ft_strlen(line) > 0)
 (...parsing etc)
    
            execute_command(&cmd,env);
        }
    }
    
    return (0);
}
```

If I call cat for exemple in my shell, and then press ctrl , it will kill cat I guess (as my prompt reappers). The problem is, if I press ctrl \ while I am not currently executing a command, it will also display the text -- which I dont want, as I just want Ctrl \ to do nothing at all, as in the real shell.

My alternative solution in execute_command :

```
                pid = fork();
                if (pid == 0)
                {
                    signal(SIGQUIT, quithandler);
                    if (execvp(command, command_args) == -1)
                    {
                        perror(">");
                        exit (127);
                    }
                }
```

But this one does not work.

Thanks a lot by advance and do not hesitate to ask me to add more details ; I do not realize what could be unclear as some elements are still unclear to me, too !

Comment: Please provide complete code as a [mre]. Also you have not clearly stated what happens when you enter the ctrl sequence with your current code.

Comment: Have you read [signal(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html), [signal(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html), and [signal-safety(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) and [termios(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) ? Did you compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then used the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger? Did you study the source code of *existing* open source programs, including [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) or [sash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell) ?